# Use string within a variable to create new variable name

Tags: r, stringr

I have code that generates a string that i want to use as a variable name later in my script. Is there a function, or easy way to accomplish this? I know this is such base question... any help is still very much appreciated.

```
Var1 <- "NewVarName"

# Need to transform the character string inside Var1 into this new variable 
  name

NewVarName <- 1 + 2
```

Comment: Maybe you need `assign` , `assign(Var1, 1+2)`

Comment: Ronak has the correct solution, but please reconsider your process. It's usually better to manage names in a `list` than it is to modify the global environment in a way that is going to appear as a non-explicit side-effect (the newly assigned name is opaque to anyone reading the code, and said opacity is less likely to cause issues in a list — where computed-name-based object assignment is an established idiom).

Comment: @ Ronak Shah Thank you for your help.

Comment: @ hrbrmstr: i can see your point, it becomes difficult to determine what the name of the new variable actually is by looking at the code. Can you recommend how to use a list if you only are working with one name at a time? Thank you for your time and interest.